# Как вручную вызвать event?

Tags: c#, события

Подписываюсь на событие. Как его принудительно вызвать?

```
xmppCon.OnPresence += new PresenceHandler(xmppCon_OnPresence);

static void xmppCon_OnPresence(object sender, Presence pres)
{
    PrintInfo(String.Format("Got presence from: {0}", pres.From.ToString()));
    PrintInfo(String.Format("type: {0}", pres.Type.ToString()));
    PrintInfo(String.Format("status: {0}", pres.Status));
    PrintInfo("");
}
```

Comment: Также, как и любую другую функцию, передав необходимые аргументы.

Comment: ну так тут event. Здесь надо делегаты и пр

Answer (score 2):

Событие принудительно вызвать, скорее всего, нельзя: нужные для этого поле или метод обычно не являются публичными.

Но вам никто не мешает вызвать метод `xmppCon_OnPresence` напрямую:

```
xmppCon_OnPresence(...)
```

Comment: Как-то вызвать всё-таки можно(рефлексия?). NSubstitute же как-то [вызывает event](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/raising-events/)

Comment: @ixSci через рефлексию можно все, но это уже тяжелая артиллерия... И да, NSubstitute - пример некорректный, поскольку эта библиотека вызывает *свое* событие (т.е. событие в объекте, который сама же и сгенерировала). Разумеется, у нее есть доступ к своему же приватному полю.